# How to use NSImage hitTestRect:withImageDestinationRect:context:hints:flipped: METHOD

Tags: iphone, nsimage

I want to use `NSImage` instance method `hitTestRect:withImageDestinationRect:context:hints:flipped:` in iPhone .

But the problem is that `NSImage` is in Appkit framework and Appkit framework is not for iPhone development. Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple.

You can't.